# Execute multiple statements inside Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute multiple statements inside a stored procedure. It's basically a serverless architecture where I cannot generate SQL scripts and run those to generate SPs or tables. The only way I have is to run the scripts via SP or Functions. Is there any clue how can I execute bulk statements programmatically. I tried with the following SP:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON   
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenerateScript]   

AS
BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Bar1]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Bar1] 
AS
BEGIN
Select Foo from Table 
END
' 
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Bar2]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Bar2] 
AS
BEGIN
Select Foo from Table 
END
' 
END

END
```

This is producing the error below:

```
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
```

Comment: I can't see any `BULK` operations in your SQL above? Are we missing something here? What is the error you're getting when you try?

Comment: `'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.` @Larnu This is a specific error which I am getting. Plus I just want to execute multiple statments inside SP. Exec statments can be SPs, or Table scripts.

Comment: minor point, but it really isn't necessary to use `sp_executesql` if you aren't parameterizing the executed command; `EXEC (N'some sql')` might be simpler to read and debug

Comment: I'd suggest it's good practice to use `sp_executesql` @MarcGravell. Considering that people use (a variance) of `EXEC ('SELECT * FROM ' + @SomeVariable + ' WHERE Column = ' + @OtherVariable)` far too often. `EXEC {Literal String}` has no option for parameterisation, where as `sp_executesql` does.

Comment: @Larnu that's a debatable point, as the table name *cannot* be parameterized, so : the statement you're using as the example is literally one where sp_executesql **is not the full answer** (yes, `@OtherVariable` can be parameterized correctly).

Comment: @AfnanAhmad what you describe are deployment scripts, not bulk inserts. Whether you run them directly or as part of a stored procedure, they are *still* deployment scripts. If you can create the `GenerateScript` why not create the rest of the stored procedures, tables as well?

Comment: @MarcGravell `+ @SomeVariable +` should be `+ QUOTENAME(@SomeVariable) +` yes, but that doesn't change that `Column = ' + @OtherVariable` isn't paramterised.

Comment: Yeah that's the point. I was thinking the same but some times we have restrictions too :) @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @Larnu  My point here: knowing why you're using sp_executesql is half the story to using it correctly. Simply telling people "use sp_executesql": doesn't help, as shown in the question here, where it is being used entirely incorrectly

Comment: @AfnanAhmad what restrictions? If you can create `GenerateScript` you *don't* have restrictions. You may have a pointless manager-mandated policy that doesn't offer any benefits while making it easier to make mistakes

Comment: @MarcGravell I am amazed how it is being used entirely incorrectly ? As I created this script from `Tasks=>Generate Scripts`

Comment: @AfnanAhmad `Generate Scripts` doesn't generate anything like what you posted here. There are multiple valid, secure, easy ways to deploy databases and changes. What you're trying here isn't one of them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This would be a whole site script. Basically a complete DB script which will execute at the creation of new site every time.

Comment: @AfnanAhmad doesn't change anything. If you check any .NET CMS, all generate their databases from scripts. None try to create one stored procedure to run DML statements - what's the point?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad you can create dacpac files. You can generate change scripts between one database version and another. You can create migration script *files* that apply changes from one db version to another, allowing you to apply all changes from v1.0 to v10.0 in sequence. All you need is to execute those script files one after the other. You don't need a stored procedure to call them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I already tried generating scripts and executing them like `DECLARE @command  VARCHAR(500)  = 'sqlcmd -S ' + @DBServerName + ' -d  ' +  @DBName + ' -i ' + '"' + @FileName + '"' 
  EXEC xp_cmdshell  @command`    . It worked well but for this I have to store files at some location like http and aws will cost for it. I am still not sure either I am at right path or not.

Comment: But surely all of your objects should be scripted in your Source Control Software...?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad why do that at all????? Just execute the **scripts** with the DDL commands

Comment: May you please @PanagiotisKanavos post your answer How to do it with DML commands. I would be great ful.

Comment: @AfnanAhmad I'd suggest you check how every other site works. Especially the CMS products like Umbraco, DotNetNuke. This isn't a new problem. The approach is completely wrong though. The source for all of them is available

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your time. I do have script files in my source control software. Will read those scripts to generate a whole DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't your `sp_executesql` commands, it's the start of your SQL (The error is literally telling you the problem). As the error tells you `CREATE`/`ALTER PROCEDURE`' must be the first statement in a query batch, however, the first command you have in your batch is `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`.

Add a `GO` between your `SET` and `ALTER` commands to start a new batch (in SSMS/`sqlcmd`):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenerateScript] ...
```

Comment: also worth observing that *immediately before* it complains `'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.`, it *tells you the line number*: `Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GenerateScript, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 0]`, and SSMS shows red squigglies on the offending line

Comment: Ohh actually I removed the `Go` statements inside SPs and it removed the above one too. Many Thanks.

Comment: This is why the **FULL** error messages are really important to include in your post @AfnanAhmad. They almost always provide very important information.

Comment: @Larnu Got it. Thank you :-)

Comment: @AfnanAhmad if this solved the problem, please do remember to make it as the solution so that it'll help other readers in the future as well. Thanks.